# Getting an error msg -Error: A value of type '_MyApp' can't be returned from a function with return type 'State<MyApp>'. How to resolve this

Tags: function, types, return

````
```
State<MyApp> createState => _MyApp();
```
Using the above code I get Error: A value of type '_MyApp' can't be returned from a function with return type 'State<MyApp>
````

Originally my issue was
_MyApp createState() => _MyApp(); but I got that Avoid using private types in public api.
I was told to use this method - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103773 to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this changed the private _MyApp to public MyApp

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp ({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}
```